# Allow collection to update from client in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Just hit an insanely frustrating roadblock in prototyping. I need to update and increment values an array inside of a collection. To do this, I'm accessing the collection using the MongoDB syntax like so:

```
 Players.update({_id: Session.get('p1_id'), 'opponents.$.id' : Session.get('p2_id')}, 
  {$inc: {
    'games_played' : 1
  }}
);
```

When this runs I get an error saying: Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]

Now, I searched the hell out of this and I know that it came down in an update and why they only allow update by id's. But my problem is that I can't seem to find a way around it. I tried forcing it by adding this to `if (Meteor.isServer)`:

```
Players.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc, fields, modifier){
   return true;
  },
  update: function(userId, doc, fields, modifier){
    return true;
  },
  remove: function(userId, doc, fields, modifier){
    return true;
  }
});
```

Nothing seems to work, and all the examples I find talk about using a Meteor method (not really sure what that is) or are doing userId validation (I dont have any users and don't want to add them right now). I'm just prototyping/sketching and I'm not concerned about security. How can I proceed here?

Comment: http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header - Basically, methods are functions that run on the server, which you can call on the client. Pass in any needed data from the client when you call the method, and run the query inside the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can make this into a method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  incrementGames: function (player1Id, player2Id) {
    check(player1Id, Meteor.Collection.ObjectID);
    check(player2Id, Meteor.Collection.ObjectID);

    Players.update({
      _id: player1Id,
      'opponents.$.id': player2Id
    }, {
      $inc: {
        'games_played' : 1
      }
    }, function(error, affectedDocs) {
      if (error) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(500, error.message);
      } else {
        return "Update Successful";
      }
    });
  }
});
```

And on your client:

```
Meteor.call("incrementGames", Session.get('p1_id'), Session.get('p2_id'), function(error, affectedDocs) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  } else {
    // Do whatever
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Cuberto, I think i get Methods a little better now. I'm trying to use your approach and define a Method in `server/methods.js` and call it on the client, but I'm getting no response. It doesn't seem to work at all, even a `console.log` doesn't do anything when I call it. Any ideas? I feel like I'm missing something big here, with the permissions stuff not working and now with methods not working.

Comment: Are you sure your `console.log`s are not getting run? They would appear in the terminal, not the browser console.

Comment: @Mike note that my `Meteor.call` in this example did not include a callback. If you include a `function(error, result)` callback as the last (in this case, 4th) parameter of `Meteor.call`, you can see what the server is responding with, or if an error occurred see my edit.

Comment: @Mike try changing the `Meteor.Collection.ObjectID`s in my code to `String`, see if that helps.

Comment: Man, you did it. You taught me about Methods and fixed my dumb problem. Thanks so much, I finally got it working. Only difference I needed to make it work for my app was to move the $ cursor from the initial selector to the increment block like this:

`$inc: { 'opponents.$.games_played' : 1 }`

Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Mike Ah yeah I was a little confused about what you were trying to do with that. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

You just got the update wrong. The first parameter of the update method should be the id. the second parameter is an object containing the modifiers.

```js
Players.update(playerId, {$inc:{games_played:1}});
```

Optionally you can add a callback containing error as the first parameter and response as the second parameter.

Comment: Hi @Phosphoros, thanks for the reply! You are correct. But I was trying something slightly diff:

I was actually trying to target the update by 2 params, first find the correct player id and then set the cursor at the opponents array value that matches. The meteor method was the trick, as the client wouldn't let me do the cursor stuff.

I was doing other stuff wrong too (this was last year), but that was the basic one.